# If C uses shared libraries, is it possible to write a program that will modify the code that opens a file

Tags: malware, operating-systems, c

If C uses shared libraries, is it possible to write a program that will modify the `fopen` function to execute a malicious code? How can the OS protect the user from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. This technique is called function hooking. In fact, you can *completely* control an executable by hooking, say, `__libc_start_main` and redirecting execution to code in the library. There is absolutely no way an OS can protect an executable from a malicious library. The code in the library will run in the same address space as the executable and will have the exact same abilities. The only way to protect an executable from a malicious library is to not link it with malicious libraries.

Comment: The interesting about that is: antivirus can't get that from my understand, right?

Comment: @Faminha102 Antivirus can't get what? If you start antivirus from a compromised environment, then you could load a malicious library with the AV, but generally it is started from a privileged location (e.g. as a service), which means that you'd need to already have high privileges to provide it with a malicious library.

Comment: @forest I assume OP meant that an Antivirus can't detect that you're trying to make some innocent program load a malicious library and thus execute malicious code. Probably OP is trying to put it into action.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Ah. Well AV will definitely try to scan the library, but obviously you could avoid AV detection in libraries just as you can in executables.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to be clear: when you modify a shared library in memory, only the copy of it in *your* process' address space gets modified. Neither the copy on the disk nor the copies in use by other processes will get modified. It's the same as modifying a global variable in a process (such as `errno`); only the one process using that address space will "see" the modification.